# TYPO3 - creating a community site

Tags: social-networking, typo3

Okay. This is the main functionality of my site. Here goes:

People register. They upload a list of whatever ebooks, movies, tv shows they have. Other people who want them will just have to 'search' for an item and they will be provided with a contact form to contact a person that has what they want. Very much like pianofiles.com but this is for a local community.
Added features could be 
 *forming social groups by interest
 *creating events
 etc..

Is all this possible using Typo3?

If yes, then *how* should I use Typo3 for it? (Just a basic idea)

If not, what should i use to create something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the TER, a quick search revealed http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/community

You could realize your project with any well known CMS or PHP framework. 
TYPO3 CMS, as I see it, has a strong emphasis on the editor backend. If you don't need that at all and don't have any prior experience, I'm not sure if it's the right tool for you - unless you want to get into TYPO3 anyway!

PS: For TYPO3 web apps, there will be the upcoming Framework http://flow.typo3.org, wich is in beta